# make cron job that excute file by wp-cron

Tags: wordpress, cron

the job that i want to accomplish is to call those two links , call the first one wait 5 seconds and call the the second one.

https://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/wp-cron.php?export_key=8gqzwGeQ7DJk&export_id=24&action=trigger

https://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/wp-cron.php?export_key=8gqzwGeQ7DJk&export_id=24&action=processing

they will export users on wordpress and send them by email .
as a solution i created a php file that will call them by $.get .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>SENDING EMAIL WITH CRON</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
            }
        }
    }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $.get('https://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/wp-cron.php?export_key=8gqzwGeQ7DJk&export_id=24&action=trigger', function(data) {

                if (data.message.indexOf("Cron job triggered.") >= 0){
                   // alert(data.message);
                    sleep(5000);
                            $.get('https://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/wp-cron.php?export_key=8gqzwGeQ7DJk&export_id=24&action=processing', function(data2) {


                            })
                        }



            });
        }); 
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

now all what i want is to call the last file every 7 days , by wp-cron or cron of cpanel .

Comment: the file that i want to excute every  7 days on monday 8 am is
https://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/send-email-recent-users.php

Comment: Look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179694/wp-schedule-event-every-day-at-specific-time)

Comment: @nmr thanks , but what i need is what i should write in the function that will be excuted every 7 days . ( i mean the function that will call this file https://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/send-email-recent-users.php )

Comment: You can use `curl` or WP class `Requests` (wrapper for curl). Try with: `Requests::post` or `Requests::get`, for example `$response = Requests::get('http://freelance.besthost-tunisie.com/send-email-recent-users.php')`.